# Разместить массив в заранее выделенной области памяти

Tags: c, функции, malloc

Подскажите, как можно массив объявленный в функции,
разместить в заранее выделенной области памяти и переданной в функцию через указатель?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int* p, int row, int col)
{
   p = (int*) malloc(row * col * sizeof(int)); // если делаю так выделяется новая область памяти, нужно чтоб разместился в area
   printf("Area ptr = %p\n", p);
}

int main()
{
   int* area = malloc(400);
   printf("Area ptr = %p", area);
   foo(area, 10, 10);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы это делаете? Уберите в функции `p = ....` и все. Или я неправильно понял ваш вопрос?

Comment: `malloc` выделяет новый блок, если вы хотите перераспределить уже выделенный используйте `realloc`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!